# ExtJS 4.2.1: How to access the Proxy from the Ext.data.Field convert function

Tags: extjs, proxy, field, reader

Is it possible to access the Proxy/Reader at the moment the convert() function of the field is executed?

According to the docs, the function accepts a value and a record as arguments.
And indeed, if you do a console.log(record) within the function, the record object is displayed (with the appropriate fields for store, proxy, etc.).

But if you try to do console.log(record.store), you will get undefined (seems that the record is not fully ready yet).

On the other side, if a small defer is issued (on the console.log(record.store)), the data is here, but it's not a solution, because in this case the convert returns nothing.

Comment: Because of how records are created, their constructors are called first, and in the constructor, the field convert methods are fired... this all happens before the record's `store` property is actually set, so that's why store is undefined, and why a defer would fix it.  Can you not move the proxy to your model definition, so then you could access it through the `record` param?

Comment: Actually, it could be a solution, but will break some other older code, that is why i'm looking for an alternative. Actually, i found a way, but my post here was hidden (do not know why). The solution is to provide a storeId for the store, and then it is available trough the store manager within the convert function together with its proxy

Comment: Hmm, interesting solution.  I always shy away from any sort of IDs like that just because of collisions/forced uniqueness, so as long as it's not a problem in your app, then go with it.

Comment: In later ExtJS versions, that is easier, but for 4.2 you might have to go up the arguments caller all the way to the reader. Something like:  arguments.callee.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.$owner.$className (which is the readers name()